# What are Minkowski space and Lorentzian manifolds, formally speaking?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, general-relativity, semi-riemannian-geometry

I am in general confused about what Minkowski space *is*. I'll write down what I know and what I believe Minkowski space is. I'd appreciate any corrections.

A Riemannian manifold is a manifold (so it locally looks like $\mathbb R^n$) equipped with a non-negative positive symmetric bilinear form (the metric).

Hyperbolic space is a *type* of Riemannian manifold, where it locally looks like $\mathbb R^n$, but globally the space has negative curvature. This gives it all of the weird properties we know and love [geodesics getting exponentially farther away, thin triangles, etc.]

'Minkowski space' naively speaking is some space $\mathbb  M \equiv \mathbb (\mathbb R^4, d)$  equipped with the metric $d(p, q) = p_0 q_0 - p_1 q_1 - p_2 q_2 - p_3 q_3$. This looks *exactly* like the [hyperboloid model of hyperbolic space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_space#The_hyperboloid_model). So it far to say that Minkowski space is *literally* the hyperboloid model of hyperbolic space?

Next, a 'Lorentzian manifold' is a pseudo-riemannian manifold which *locally* looks like Minkowski space $\mathbb M$ [contrast with the Riemannian manifold which locally looks like $\mathbb R^n$]. Globally, it is is given by a manifold which is equipped with a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form: note that here, the metric can be *negative definite*.

When we talk about a 'flat Lorentzian manifold', we are talking about how the different 'local Minkowski spaces' fit together. A flat Lorentzian manifold is still *hyperbolic*, because minkowski space is hyperbolic. Rather, the *flat* here refers to the fact that there is no curvature *across* the local Minkowski spaces fitting together. So we are to imagine many copies of Minkowski space, each of which fit together 'perfectly', and hence there is no curvature. But locally, the manifold is Minkowski, and thus has constant negative curvature 'at each local point'. Wikipedia talks about the phrase [locally flat

Is this correct? am I completely off? I find this very confusing, because [Wikipedia keeps talking about float Lorentzian manifolds. To quote:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold#Properties_of_pseudo-Riemannian_manifolds)

> Just as Euclidean space $\mathbb {R} ^{n}$can be thought of as the model Riemannian manifold, Minkowski space $\mathbb {R} ^{n-1,1}$  with the flat Minkowski metric is the model Lorentzian manifold.

My understanding of the situation is that because in a Pseudo-Riemannian manifold we can have the metric be *negative*, we can simply set the metric to $diag(1, -1, -1, -1)$ and get hyperbolic space. This is flat because the second derivatives vanish (indeed, the first derivatives vanish), and hence the space cannot have curvature. On the other hand, in the Riemannian case, we need to setup the hyperbolicity through curvature by assembling copies of $\mathbb R^n$.

Is what I have written sane, or am I completely off the mark? I'm looking for clarifications and spotting mistakes in my mental model of the physics I am studying with the math that I know.

Comment: See [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214453900) for "flat Lorentzian manifolds".

Comment: In the above definition a flat Lorentzian manifold is not hyperbolic.

Comment: @DietrichBurde can you expand on why? As far as I can see, we have the equivalence (i) flat lorentzian manifold (ii) metric constant metric $diag(1, -1, -1, -1)$ (iii) minkowski space [minknowski space has the same metric] (iv) hyperboloid model of hyperbolic space [minkowski space is a model of hyperbolic space]

Comment: The definition (see my comment) says $k=0$ for flat Lorentzian, and not $k=-1$, which is hyperbolic (constant curvature).

Comment: I see. In that case, do you know what the wiki page is talking about when it says 'flat Minkowski metric'?

Comment: It may help clear some of your confusion by emphasizing that the hyperboloid model of the hyperbolic plane refers not to the Minkowski space itself, rather the geometry of the hyperboloid sitting inside Minkowski space (the same way spherical geometry is the geometry on the sphere sitting inside flat $\mathbb{R}^3$)

Comment: Your description of Riemannian manifolds seems a little off to me. A Riemannian manifold is a manifold $M$ equipped with a positive definite symmetric bilinear form **on the tangent space $T_p M$ for each $p \in M$**. There is not just *one* positive symmetric bilinear form as your wording seems to suggest; instead each of the individual vector spaces $T_p M$ has its own positive symmetric bilinear form. And your definition of Lorentzian manifolds seems off in the same manner.

Comment: @Khanickus can you expand on this point of view? So you are saying that a hyperboloid can be fit into minkowski space, but minkowski space s larger than just the hyperboloid?

Comment: @LeeMosher Indeed, I am sorry for not being precise in my definition. I did indeed mean what you wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to know is that the sign of the Lorentzian metric on Minkowski space, which is well adapted for applications to special relativity, is poorly adapted for applications to hyperbolic geometry. If you want to construct the hyperboloid model of hyperbolic space, start instead with the Lorentzian metric of opposite sign:
$$d(p,q) = -p_0 q_0 + p_1 q_1 + p_2 q_2 + p_3 q_3
$$
In order to get around this confusion for the isolated purposes of this answer I am going to do something terrible and henceforth refer to this as "anti-Minkowski space".

The second thing is that anti-Minkowski space is not *literally* the same as the hyperboloid model. Instead, the hyperboloid model is one of the two components the subspace of anti-Minkowski space that is cut out by the equation $d(p,p)=-1$, namely the component containing the point $p = (1,0,0,0)$, and thus it is one of the sheets of the two-sheeted hyperboloid $-p_0^2 + p_1^2 + p_2^2 + p^3_3 = -1$, or equivalently $p_0^2 - p_1^2 - p_2^2 - p_3^2 = +1$. This leads to several important differences:

- Anti-Minkowski space is 4-dimensional, whereas the hyperboloid model is a 3-dimensional manifold.
- The anti-Lorentzian metric on anti-Minkowski space is indefinite, with signature $(-1,1,1,1)$, whereas the restriction of that anti-Lorentzian metric to the tangent spaces of the hyperboloid model is positive definite, i.e. it has signature $(1,1,1)$.
- Anti-Minkowki space, and anti-Lorentzian manifolds more generally, are *not* hyperbolic manifolds. By definition, a hyperbolic manifold is a Riemannian manifold of constant negative sectional curvature $-1$, in particular the metric on each tangent space is positive definite. By contrast, the metric on each tangent space of a general anti-Lorentzian manifold is indefinite.

So, your paragraph "When we talk about..." is quite a bit off the mark.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I feel this helps a bunch. I have more confusions, it would be amazing if you could answer them: (i) if I compute the curvature of the section $d(p, p) = -1$, it will work out to $-1$? (ii) Is this anti-minkowski space a manifold, even? (iii) If it is, what is the value of the curvature as a _function of the position_ for Minkowski space? [Is there some place I can find a reference?] (iv) If it is not, then what are the structures carried by Minkowski space? (v) is there an axiomatic definition of minkowski space?

Comment: For (i), yes. For (ii), yes it is a manifold; the concept of a manifold has nothing whatsoever to do with what kind of metric one might later wish to impose on that manifold, it has only to do with the existence of an atlas of coordinate charts. For (iii) and (iv), I would suggest you look that up in the reference given in the comment of @DietrichBurde. For (v), that's a little vague and I'm not sure what you mean, you correctly defined Minkowski space in your question; but perhaps there is an interesting mathematical question there, if you can formulate it better.

Comment: For (ii) I was wondering what the atlas is going to be. I don't think it's the 'stupid' atlas with a single chart, because Minkowski space does not globally look like $\mathbb{R}^n$.  For (v), I can explain through analogy. We can uniquely define a sphere as a space with constant positive sectional curvature. Is there such a set of 'geometric' properties that pin down Minkowski space?

Comment: For (ii), it is *exactly* the stupid atlas. **As a manifold**, *ignoring all metric properties*, Minkowski space is identical to $\mathbb R^n$. It is only when you introduce metric properties that the mathematical difference between Minkowski space and $\mathbb R^n$ emerges.

Comment: OK, in which case I am very confused. As a Pseudo-Riemannian manifold, Minkowski space has tangent space with the bilinear form you wrote above, right? $d(p, q) = -p_0 q_0 + p_1 q_1 + p_2 q_2 + p_3 q_3$? Thus they cannot be isomorphic as Psuedo-Riemannian manifolds? [because $R^n$ has the 'usual' inner product]. I guess you are pointing out that as _topological_ manifolds Minkowski space and $\mathbb R^n$ are the same?

Comment: Am I getting my definitions wrong? If I understand correctly, we need a chart to be a homeomorphism to map an open neighborhood of Minkowski space to  an open subset  of $\mathbb R^n$. In the Riemannian case, since our inner product is positive definite, we can 'align' the chart so that the inner product matches the Euclidian inner product. In the Minkowski space case, what happens? If we take the dumb chart, it's going to change the inner product, right? But that's not 'faithful', so any calculus we do with respect to the coordinate system will be incorrect?

Comment: I thinks it's more a question of misunderstanding the definitions you wrote. By definition, a Lorentzian manifold consists of: (1) a smooth manifold $M$; (2) a smoothly varying nondegenerate inner product on the tangent spaces of $M$. For the particular case of Minkowski space, that smooth manifold $M$ is $\mathbb R^n$. Perhaps a good textbook on Riemannian geometry might help for understanding these points.

Comment: I've explained the source of my confusion here, I don't believe it has to do with the definition of a Lorentzian manifold, rather it has to do with why I believe calculus 'works' on a Riemannian manifold: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3731331/how-does-topology-work-when-taking-charts-on-a-psuedo-riemannian-manifold. It would be amazing if you could take a look. Thanks a lot for your help on this so far :)