# How does calculus work on a Pseudo Riemannian manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry, special-relativity

I'll first recapitulate the why calculus works for Riemannian manifolds, and then present why I believe the same does not work for Pseudo-Riemannian manifolds. I'd like to know where my current model of the situation breaks down.

A differentiable manifold $M$ of dimension $n$ is a topological space $M$ equipped with an open cover $A$ (the atlas) such that for each chart $C_i \in A$, we have a homeomorphism $\phi_i: C_i \rightarrow U_i\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ [we take the subspace topology on $C_i$]. Now, for the manifold to be a *differentiable manifold*, we also ask that for all charts $C_i, C_j$ such that $C_i \cap  C_j \neq \emptyset$, the map $\phi_j \circ \phi_i^{-1}: U_i \subseteq \mathbb R^n \rightarrow U_j \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is *smooth*: That is, our change-of-coordinates maps are smooth maps.

At this point, we can define calculus on the manifold. We now define the tangent space at a point $p \in M$, where $p \in C_p$ [$C_p$ is in the cover]. We have $\phi_p: C_p \rightarrow U_p \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ as the local chart. The tangent space $T_p M$ is the collection of all smooth curves $\{ c: [-1, 1] \rightarrow C_i \mid c(0) = p \}$. But we want to impose an equivalence relation on these curves, to consider curves that have equal velocities at $p$ to be equivalent curves. So we define $c_1 \sim c_2 \iff (\phi_p \circ c_1)'(0) = (\phi_p \circ c_2)'(0)$
. One can check that this gives a vector space of dimension $n$.

- Note that we need the differentiable structure of $\mathbb R^n$ for this definition to work. In particular, we need ideals such as limits behave 'the same' in both $C_p$ and $U_p$ [the coordinate system for $C_p$]. We are guaranteed this will happen because $C_p$ is homeomorphic.
- We know that all of these calculations are not dependent on the coordinate system because we have assumed that changing coordinates is smooth. Hence we always switch to an alternative coordinate system and suffer no change. The Jacobian of the change-of-coordinates map $\phi_j \circ \phi_i^{-1}$  induces an isomorphism of tangent spaces.

When we now go to the Riemannian case and impose an inner product $\langle \cdot \vert \cdot \rangle_p: T_p M \times T_pM \rightarrow \mathbb R$ at each point $p$, we are guaranteed that this inner product does not disturb the topological considerations needed by the above differentiable structure thanks to [equivalence of norm in a finite dimensional vector space](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/equivalence-of-norms-in-a-finite-dimensional-linear-space). The topology induced by $\langle \cdot \vert \cdot \rangle_p$ is the same as the standard topology, and hence our manipulations of calculus 'are compatible' with our choice of inner product.

If we now consider the Pseudo-Riemannian case, the bilinear form $\{\cdot \mid \cdot\}: T_p M \times T_p M \rightarrow \mathbb R$ need not be positive definitite (and hence need not induce an inner product). The way this bilinear form 'sees the space in local coordinates' can be pretty weird.

For example, let us take Minkowski space $M \equiv (\mathbb R^4, \{ \cdot \mid \cdot \})$ such that $\{ \mathbf p, \mathbf q \} \equiv -p_0 q_0 + p_1 q_1 + p_2 q_2 + p_3 q_3$. Then for vectors $\mathbf v = (t, x, 0, 0), \mathbf w = (x, t, 0, 0)$, we have $\{v, w \} = 0$, while the regular inner product $v \cdot w = 2xt$. So this bilinear form does not induce any reasonable norm (and hence no topology).

Given all of this, why is it legal for us *to still perform computations on the tangent space* in a Pseudo Riemannian manifold? As far as I can tell, the 'bilinear form' structure is in no way compatible with the differentiable structure of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: We don't really need a metric at all to do calculus on a smooth manifold. It's true that a pseudo-Riemannian metric does not generate the topology in the same way that a Riemannian metric does, but the manifold is generally taken to be a topological space before we define a metric on it.

Comment: @Kajelad Right, so my discomfort is in this 'incompatibility' between the norms.I fear that something may go wrong [though I do not really see what], and I'd like to understand why nothing goes awry. I can clearly see that the data defined thus far (including $T_p M$) doesn't define on the bilinear form $\{ \cdot \mid \cdot \}$.

Comment: Nothing goes wrong; As with other types of local structure (e.g. symplectic forms), one just treats them as extra pieces of data with no real bearing on the topology. When doing calculus, you can simply "forget" this extra structure and proceed using the smooth structure only. The one loss is that you can't use geodesic distance to study the topological properties of the manifold in the same way you can in the Riemannian case.

Comment: @Kajelad I'd be glad if you can document the kinds of failures that occur because the topology is not generated by this bilinear form; I'd also be glad if you can point to some other algebraic structure we can impose on Minkowski space that is better aligned with the bilinear form?